# Add variable number of XElements

Tags: c#

I'm writing an app to read a binary plist, then output some of the data to an XML file, but have hit somewhat of a hurdle. Here is my current code:

```
BinaryPlistReader bpr = new BinaryPlistReader();
IDictionary plist = bpr.ReadObject(outputFolder + "\\Info.plist");
string name = plist["CFBundleName"].ToString();
string bundle = plist["CFBundleIdentifier"].ToString();
var icons = plist["CFBundleIconFiles"];

XElement apps = 
    new XElement("Applications",
        new XElement("Application",
            new XAttribute("Name", name),
            new XAttribute("CFBundleIdentifier", bundle),

            new XElement("Icon", "filename",
                new XAttribute("Size", "icon size")
                )
            )
        );
apps.Save(outputFolder + "\\" + name + ".xml");
```

I want to do something like this:

```
XElement apps = 
    new XElement("Applications",
        new XElement("Application",
            new XAttribute("Name", name),
            new XAttribute("CFBundleIdentifier", bundle),

            foreach (var icon in icons)
            {
                // Calculate icon size
                new XElement("Icon", icon,
                    new XAttribute("Size", iconsize)
            }
                )
            )
        );
apps.Save(outputFolder + "\\" + name + ".xml");
```

But I can't have an enumerator in the middle of my definition of an XElement, so I'm not sure how to do this. I also don't really know how to enumerate through my icons object despite having looked at SO answers for the past hour.

If someone could help me out here I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ

```
XElement apps = 
new XElement("Applications",
    new XElement("Application",
        new XAttribute("Name", name),
        new XAttribute("CFBundleIdentifier", bundle),
        (from icon in icons
        select new XElement("Icon", icon,
                new XAttribute("Size", iconsize)))
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks so much, my LINQ is awful. I'm seeing this error now though: 

"Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'.  'Select' not found."

How can I enumerate through my object? I've never worked with them before now.

Comment: what is the type of icons ? and you need `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I've managed to convert it to a string array which your LINQ has no problems enumerating through and it's all working perfectly now, thanks for your help!